# Yaml - how to make conditions from branches

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, appveyor

Spent a lot of time making yaml :(

I've read https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/ - didn't help

```
-
branches:
    only:
      - master
    version: 0.3.0.{build}
    environment: release
    packageVersion: 0.3.0.{build}
-
branches:
    only:
      - develop
    version: 0.2.3.{build}
    environment: debug
    packageVersion: 0.2.3.beta-{build}

dotnet_csproj:
    patch: true
    file: '**\Project.csproj'
    version: '{version}'
    package_version: $(nugetVersion)
    assembly_version: $(buildVersion)
    file_version: $(buildVersion)
    informational_version: $(nugetVersion)

before_build:
   - nuget restore

build:
    verbosity: minimal

//More code
```

How can I set versioning from the branch? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is number of issues with this YAML:

- YAML syntax is very sensitive to spaces
- `environment` section is used to set environment variables, but seems used for configuration.

Working YAML:

```
-
  branches:
    only:
      - master
  version: 0.3.0.{build}
  configuration: release
  environment:
    packageVersion: 0.3.0.{build}
-
  branches:
      only:
        - develop
  version: 0.2.3.{build}
  configuration: debug
  environment:
    packageVersion: 0.2.3.beta-{build}

  dotnet_csproj:
      patch: true
      file: '**\Project.csproj'
      version: '{version}'
      package_version: $(nugetVersion)
      assembly_version: $(buildVersion)
      file_version: $(buildVersion)
      informational_version: $(nugetVersion)

  before_build:
     - nuget restore

  build:
      verbosity: minimal
```

However with this YAML sections like `dotnet_csproj`, `build` and `before_build` will work only for `develop` branch. If you need them to work for both, use https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#sharing-common-configuration-between-branches.

Sample YAML:

```
#common configuration
dotnet_csproj:
    patch: true
    file: '**\Project.csproj'
    version: '{version}'
    package_version: $(nugetVersion)
    assembly_version: $(buildVersion)
    file_version: $(buildVersion)
    informational_version: $(nugetVersion)

before_build:
  - nuget restore

build:
  verbosity: minimal

#branches specific configuration
for:
-
  branches:
    only:
      - master
  version: 0.3.0.{build}
  configuration: release
  environment:
    packageVersion: 0.3.0.{build}
-
  branches:
      only:
        - develop
  version: 0.2.3.{build}
  configuration: debug
  environment:
    packageVersion: 0.2.3.beta-{build}
```

Also not sure where `$(nugetVersion)` and `$(buildVersion)` environment variables are supposed to come from, but this is subject of separate discussion.